# Map not work while after add firebase to the project

Tags: flutter

This is the error thrown by flutter
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: plugins.flutter.io/google_maps

```
 configurations {
    implementation.exclude module:'protobuf-lite'
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Stop debugging and rebuild the app.
2. Clean build cache:
   `flutter clean`
3. Run in terminal:
   `flutter channel master`
   `flutter upgrade`

Comment: again same issue